# how can the PL/SQL datatype BINARY_INTEGER materialized as Java types?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

What would be the datatype in java equivalent to the PL/SQL datatype BINARY_INTEGER?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm#CHDBJAGH), we can map it to either `oracle.sql.NUMBER` or a straightforward `int` primitive.

Answer (score 1):

[`BINARY_INTEGER`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/BINARY_INTEGER) is a subtype of INTEGER and ranges from `-2^31` to `2^31`, same size as the `int` type in `java`, so you could use `int`.

(Another equivalent type in `PL/SQL` to `BINARY_INTEGER` is [`PLS_INTEGER`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/03_types.htm) and this one is faster in most operations).

Answer (score 0):

If you're lazy in reading the documentation, then you could also play a bit with `ResultSet#getObject()` to see what default type the JDBC driver returns and then use it.

```
System.out.println(resultSet.getObject("columnname").getClass());
```